# How to install multiple instances of an app in Arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman, aur

I've searched a lot but with no success.
my problem is that I want to install multiple instances of an application in Arch Linux. to be more specific, I want 2-3 instances of latest Skype. one for my working stuff, one for personal usage and one for university. each of them should have different directories, different desktop entries and different settings. this is not just about Skype. in windows it's very easy. you just make the path of installation different and you have another instance. but in Linux I can't do that. I wanted to know how to do that for other software also.

I thinks it should be done via custom packaging but don't know where to start!

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this depends on the target application. Many applications do not need to be installed twice, because they allow specifying the directory where they read/store their configuration files. Others have support for multiple profiles built-in (firefox -P). It's hard to give an answer for _all_ possible applications.

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You are not asking how to solve your problem. You are asking how to solve a problem that you got while solving your problem.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there is usually no point in installing more than one copy of the same package. It won't solve your issue the way you apparently think, because the place a program stores _your_ data (account, sessions, local storage...) does not depend on the place the package is installed in, nor on how the package is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you are looking for the wrong thing.  The program (binaries) and the settings are very different things. The same program binaries can be used to work with different settings (eg for different users).

On Windows there was once a trend to store settings with the application in "Program Files" but this is getting less and less common.  Usually settings for user applications are stored somewhere in your home directory both on Windows and Linux.  On Linux the equivalent to storing settings in the application directory is storing them in `/etc`.  This means that even if you did install it twice you would end up with everything pointing at the same settings.

---

You are looking for a way to run the application twice with different settings.

The `HOME` environment variable is usually set to the location of your home directory. Applications which use the home directory for their settings might just read the `HOME` environment variable.  Changing it before running the application should be sufficient for those.  You can do this on the command line or write a trivial shell script to do so.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/.work
export HOME=~/.work
skype
```

If that doesn't work then applications may need a much more extreme measure of setting up and using a [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot) environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy and clean way to do it, is to launch them (the applications) from ** different users**.
In this way the binary executed is the same (from */usr*, etc.) but `$HOME` is different.

This solution has some important drawbacks that could be likely incompatible with your needs:

- you need one new user for every instance
- can't *share* easily data between them

---

An *evolution* of this concept would be to launch applications using **virtual machines**;
I see it as an evolution of the previous solution because it overcomes issues described above:

- new instances can be create easily by *cloning* VMs
- data can be shared *easily* between VMs and between VM and host

The drawback is the high demanded resources,
but just to remember, *this is the **ratio** upstream the invention of VM!*